# Error when compiling after importing into my solution the sp-page-context npm package

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, angular2

I am getting this error when I import the `sp-page-context` into my angular solution:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/SPCoreLibraryStrings.resx.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'resx-strings' in 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX\node_modules@microsoft\sp-core-library\lib'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/sp-dynamic-data/lib/loc/Strings.resx.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'resx-strings' in 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX\node_modules@microsoft\sp-dynamic-data\lib\loc'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/sp-page-context/lib/loc/Strings.resx.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'resx-strings' in 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX\node_modules@microsoft\sp-page-context\lib\loc'

Answer (score 0):

Try running below commands on in your package:

```
npm i @microsoft/sp-core-library
npm i @microsoft/sp-dynamic-data
npm i @microsoft/sp-page-context
```

Also, make sure you have `"ControlStrings": "node_modules/@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/loc/{locale}.js"` in your `localizedResources` in `config.json` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/issues/124).